# EF Core: Argument type is not assignable to parameter

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have some inheritance chain which start from interface and endsup with actual implmenetation going a couple of steps.

However, this code is 100% correct

```
IBaseModel model = new ErrorModel();
```

But when I'm trying something like that:

```
class MyContext: DbContext{
    public DbSet<ErrorModel> Errors {get; set}
}
```

and later

```
DbSet<IBaseModel> set = new MyContext().Errors
```

this not working *(not compiled)* and say that *Argument Type `DbSet<ErrorModel>` is not assignable to parameter `DbSet<IBaseModel>`*

What is the problem there and how to resolve it?

---

UPD1: It's also not working if I'm using base class instead of interface. And code like this

```
IQueryable<IBaseModel> tests = new MyContext().Errors
```

also compiled without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working, because `DbSet<Item>` not inherited from `DbSet<BaseItem>` and it's logically quite difference things, because `DbSet<>` is a mutable structure. You could add `BaseItem` into `DbSet<BaseItem>` but ofcourse you can't add it to `DbSet<Item>` so this will not work. With the same reason you can't convert lists or other mutable structures.

However, for immutable structures like `IEnumerable` or `IReadOnlyCollection` this conversion will work just fine.